# ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: poll can't be stopped

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to invoke the `telegramBot.stopPoll()` function but I am getting error

```
ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: poll can't be stopped
```

I want to stop the poll when a desired person (userId) answers the poll.

Here is my function which create the poll and stops the poll.

```
function sendJacuzziMaintenancePoll(chatId, userName){

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var question = "Jacuzzi Maintenance QA checklist. @"+userName+" Please mark you think you have done.";
        var answers = ["Water quality check", "Post the picture of the PH test stripe to the Telegram group", "Check the current temperature and post the picture to the Telegram group"];

        var pollMessageId = null;

        var reply_markup  = JSON.stringify({
            'force_reply': true,
            'selective' : true
        });

        const opts = {
            'is_anonymous': false,
            'allows_multiple_answers': true,
            'reply_markup': reply_markup
        };

        // set poll_answer listener so that we can stop the poll when answered by the desired user
        // This will be called when a user answer a poll
        telegramBot.addListener("poll_answer", function (response) {
            console.log("poll_answer response", response);
            // Remove listner first
            telegramBot.removeListener("poll_answer");

            // Check the same user
             if (userName === response.user.username){
                 let message = "@" + userName + " " + STRINGS.BOT_MESSAGE_THANKYOU_FOR_POLL_VOTE;
                 sendMessage(chatId, message);

                 //Stop the POLL
                 telegramBot.stopPoll(chatId, pollMessageId);

             } else {
                 let message = "@" + userName + " --" + STRINGS.BOT_MESSAGE_THANKYOU_FOR_POLL_VOTE;
                 sendMessage(chatId, message);
             }
        })
    
        telegramBot.sendPoll(chatId, question, answers, opts).then(function(response){
            pollMessageId = response.message_id;
            resolve(response);
        }).catch(function(err){
            reject(err);
        })
    })
}
```

Note: I save the pollMessageId from the response when poll is sent, then I pass that pollMessageId to stop the poll.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the completed stacktrace.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: poll can't be stopped
    at /Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js:284:15
    at tryCatcher (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/qadirhussain/workspace/nodeJS/qRoomCleaningBot/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Comment: is that a complete stack trace? Also, I couldn't find `stopPolling` method in the lib which takes 2 arguments. It just takes and option as an obect.

Comment: stopPolling is an other function. I am talking about stopPoll()

Comment: MY bad for some reason I saw `stopPolling`.

Comment: Could you please check if for some reason `pollMessageId` is null in your call?

Comment: @Dipen Shah, no its not null bro. Already checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but I believe it's a bug on Telegram Bot API's implementation when dealing with `ForceReply` markup (because the other `reply_markup` options like inline buttons work just fine). Remove that markup and it should work just fine.

```
...
const opts = {
    'is_anonymous': false,
    'allows_multiple_answers': true,
    // 'reply_markup': reply_markup // remove this
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the direction, after removing the reply-markup i.e force reply it worked like charm. Thank you.